# How to split a 30 amp 120v circuit to allow a sub panel containing two 20 amp 120vbreakers

Tags: electrical, subpanel

I have an existing 30A 120v circuit breaker in my main panel which has been used to power a computer server rack and backup battery. A 30 foot long 10 gage 3 wire (black, white and green) extension cord with 30 amp rated connectors on each end has been used to connect the rack. I no longer need the server rack and am downgrading to a much smaller setup.  I need to install a sub panel with two 20 Amp 120v breakers powered by the main panel through the extension cable.  I need to split the black (hot wire) to feed each of the 2 sub breakers in the sub panel and use the white (common) and green (ground) as common connections for both of the two circuit breakers in the sub panel.  Is this approach possible and will it meet code?

Comment: If it is a real extension cable it needs to be replaced with a proper electrical cable or wires in conduit.  The rest should be easy.

Comment: In sub panels, the neutral(white) and the ground(green) must be isolated(not bonded) to each other.  Just make sure any bonding screws/wires are removed(should be subs).